# how to call associating values to drop menu choices

Tags: excel, vba

i have a table in exel 
column 1 = bolt sizes in imperial values
column 2 = bolt sizes in metric values
now a called the column 1 ''bolt_size'' and created a drop menu where you can choose between all the different possible sizes (in imperial) but as for the rest of the sheet i need the metric values.

what i have been tryinh to do is once the choice in selected in the drop menu, the second value (the metric one) appears in a chosen cell where the rest of the sheet will call that value for further calcuations.

I have sucessfully made that cell display 1 - 10 (when choosing from the drop menu) instead of the actual values associated with the bolts.

Please help guide me in the right direction

Comment: What kind of dropDownValue menu is it ?  Are you using a data validation list?  You should be able to use vlookup to map the selected value to the metric equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a Form Control/ Combobox, and you have specified its `Cell link`, then it will display the index number of the selected item, rather than the actual value. In a cell enter the following formula that uses the linked-cell's value to retrieve the text from the input range:

```
=INDEX(C2:C4,D6)
```

C2:C4 is the `Input range` and D6 is the `Cell link`.

If you are not using a Form Control then you'll need to clarify your question.